# Doctrine 2 nested set - retrieve full tree in single query

Tags: doctrine-orm, nested-sets, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions

I'm using [stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) (Bundle wrapper for [Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions)) to implement a Nested Set (tree) entity. The entity is configured and working, but I can't figure out how to retrieve all root notes with all of their children (full trees) in a single query. I currently have the full collection returning however it lazy loads all children, meaning a large number of queries is performed.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution.

1. retrieve full list of node objects:

   ```
   $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('NestedEntity');
   $nodes = $repo->getChildren();
   ```
2. build tree with your nodes.

   ```
   $tree = $repo->getRepoUtils()->buildTreeArray($nodes);
   ```
3. buildTreeArray method accepts array of node-arrays, so you must implement ArrayAccess interface in your Entity. Also it puts all children in `__children` key of node-array.

   ```
   /**
    * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
    * @ORM\Table(name="nested_entity")
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
    */
    class NestedEntity implements \ArrayAccess
    {

        public function offsetExists($offset)
        {
            return property_exists($this, $offset);
        }

        public function &offsetGet($offset)
        {
            return $this->$offset;
        }

        public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
        {
            $this->$offset = $value;
        }

        public function offsetUnset($offset)
        {
            $this->$offset = null;
        }

        protected $__children = [];

        ...
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `childrenHierarchy()` method for whole tree retrieve:

```
$tree = $repo->childrenHierarchy();
```